# Hash Code what Is this?

Tags: java, arrays, class, hash

```
int value = 5381;

for (int i = 0; i < item.length(); i++) {
  value = value * 33 + item.charAt(i);
}

value &= 0x7fffffff;
value %= size;
```

This is Bernstein's hash code. I get everything except for the last two lines. What do they do? They also produce an error in the Java compiler, so they are clearly not valid code. How else could they be represented?

I almost don't care what they do, as long as they work lol :P

Comment: If there's ever a Java operator you don't recognise, then just type "Java operators" into Google.

Comment: Conpiles (and runs) fine for me.  You do, of course, have to define `item` as a String and `size` as an int.  `item` is the string you're hashing, and `size` is the size of the hashtable that you will index with the resulting `value`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of the bitwise and `&` is to shift all values into a positive integer range.  This probably preserves the even distribution created by the former operations better than a simple absolute value operation.  Also, the general reason for getting rid of the negative sign, as @yshavit points out in the comments, is that the `value` will probably eventually be used as an index of some sort.

The purpose of the modulo `%` is to make the hash code fit in a limited sized space.

Comment: I think I'm figuring it out. The bitwise part removes the sign (+/-) of the result, in the event that it is negative. I don't know why on earth you don't just run the absolute value function on it though... this is how the function was provided. This is not my code and it does work / is accurate.

Comment: Apparently it removes any negative values. I'm assuming negative values make hash functions ugly.

Comment: @user: Because clearing the sign bit is not the same as `abs`.

Comment: Ahhh ok. So instead of wasting resources calling an absolute value function, it does it on a more machine/basic level, optimizing the code so it can perform? That makes sense to me.. make sense to you?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth How so? -10 becomes 10... 10 stays 10... If you say it's not the same, you see something I'm missing. Please explain.

Comment: @user: Because you aren't considering how [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representation#Two.27s_complement) works...

Comment: Try this: `System.out.println(-10 & 0x7FFFFFFF);`

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Essentially, in binary, positive and negative numbers are represented quite differently. It's not useful to me to go through that two's-compliment piece, but I see the idea.

Comment: @user You should go through it at some point, though. Two's complement is going to come up again and again throughout your programming career.

Comment: Also, @The111, re the purpose of making the integer non-negative (not positive), it's probably not just to make the mod function more evenly distributed. The mod function takes the sign of its first argument (jls [15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)), and if `value` is going to be used as the index of an array or list, then it's important that it's not negative.

Comment: @yshavit Very true, but what I meant to say was that using this method of removing the sign might preserve even distribution better than a simple absolute value.  I will edit to clarify that and include your points.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) is still negative. ;)

Answer (score 3):

`&` is bitwise AND and, `%` is modulo.

`&=` and `%=` is obviously a shorthand of those operations and `=`.

Comment: They aren't shorthand for `=`, `x (op) y` is _actually_ shorthand for x = x (op) y` (or at least it should be if you are using a custom data type)

Comment: Um, huh? That would mean `int x=1; x + 1;` is shorthand for `int x=1; x=x+1;` which is definitely not true.